# Forms not closing when they should

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

Hey all, i have a problem with trying to get 2 forms to close at different times using a timer on each of the 2 forms.

This is my form layout:

frmMain
Frm1
Frm2

Frm1 and Frm2 are identical to each other. FrmMain has 2 buttons on it. One button to call Frm1 and the other to call Frm2.

Frm1 and Frm2 each has a timer. It counts down to 0 and then does a .close(). However, if i pause between clicking the second button they both seem to always disappears at the same time.

I would do something like this...

Click on the first button (showing the Frm1 form)
wait about 10 secs...
Click on the second button (showing the Frm2 form)
they both are shown on screen...
then they both disappear at the same time.... which shouldn't happen since i clicked the Frm2 box 10 seconds AFTER Frm1... So Frm1 should hide before Frm2 does...but it does not.

Any help to this problem would be great! :)

**updated with code**

```
Public Sub showMessageBox(ByVal typeOfBox As String, ByVal theMessage As String)
    If Form2.theNumOpened <= 6 Then
        Form2.theNumOpened = Form2.theNumOpened + 1 'ADDED

        Me.Opacity = 0
        Me.Show()

        Select Case Form2.theNumOpened
            Case 1
                Me.Text = "NBMsg1"
                Me.SetDesktopLocation(My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.Width - 350, 5)
            Case 2
                Me.Text = "NBMsg2"
                Dim hwnd As IntPtr = FindWindow(vbNullString, "NBMsg1")
                SetWindowPos(hwnd, 0, My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.Width - 350, Me.Height + 10, 0, 0, 1)
                Me.SetDesktopLocation(My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.Width - 350, 5)
            Case 3
                Me.Text = "NBMsg3"
                Dim hwnd As IntPtr = FindWindow(vbNullString, "NBMsg2")
                SetWindowPos(hwnd, 0, My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.Width - 350, Me.Height + 10, 0, 0, 1)
                hwnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, "NBMsg1")
                SetWindowPos(hwnd, 0, My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.Width - 350, (Me.Height * 2) + 15, 0, 0, 1)
                Me.SetDesktopLocation(My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.Width - 350, 5)
            Case 4
                Me.Text = "NBMsg4"
                Dim hwnd As IntPtr = FindWindow(vbNullString, "NBMsg3")
                SetWindowPos(hwnd, 0, My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.Width - 350, Me.Height + 10, 0, 0, 1)
                hwnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, "NBMsg2")
                SetWindowPos(hwnd, 0, My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.Width - 350, (Me.Height * 2) + 15, 0, 0, 1)
                hwnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, "NBMsg1")
                SetWindowPos(hwnd, 0, My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.Width - 350, (Me.Height * 3) + 20, 0, 0, 1)
                Me.SetDesktopLocation(My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.Width - 350, 5)
            Case 5
                Me.Text = "NBMsg5"
                Dim hwnd As IntPtr = FindWindow(vbNullString, "NBMsg4")
                SetWindowPos(hwnd, 0, My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.Width - 350, Me.Height + 10, 0, 0, 1)
                hwnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, "NBMsg3")
                SetWindowPos(hwnd, 0, My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.Width - 350, (Me.Height * 2) + 15, 0, 0, 1)
                hwnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, "NBMsg2")
                SetWindowPos(hwnd, 0, My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.Width - 350, (Me.Height * 3) + 20, 0, 0, 1)
                hwnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, "NBMsg1")
                SetWindowPos(hwnd, 0, My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.Width - 350, (Me.Height * 4) + 25, 0, 0, 1)
                Me.SetDesktopLocation(My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.Width - 350, 5)
            Case 6
                Me.Text = "NBMsg6"
                Dim hwnd As IntPtr = FindWindow(vbNullString, "NBMsg5")
                SetWindowPos(hwnd, 0, My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.Width - 350, Me.Height + 10, 0, 0, 1)
                hwnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, "NBMsg4")
                SetWindowPos(hwnd, 0, My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.Width - 350, (Me.Height * 2) + 15, 0, 0, 1)
                hwnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, "NBMsg3")
                SetWindowPos(hwnd, 0, My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.Width - 350, (Me.Height * 3) + 20, 0, 0, 1)
                hwnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, "NBMsg2")
                SetWindowPos(hwnd, 0, My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.Width - 350, (Me.Height * 4) + 25, 0, 0, 1)
                hwnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, "NBMsg1")
                SetWindowPos(hwnd, 0, My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.Width - 350, (Me.Height * 5) + 30, 0, 0, 1)
                Me.SetDesktopLocation(My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.Width - 350, 5)
            Case Else
                Me.Close()
                Me.Dispose()
        End Select

        isLoading = True
        theType = typeOfBox
        lblSaying.Text = theMessage

        If typeOfBox = "OK" Then
            Me.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(192, 255, 192)
        ElseIf typeOfBox = "ERR" Then
            Me.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 192, 192)
        Else
            Me.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 192)
        End If

        If Len(theMessage) <= 30 Then
            howLong = 4000
        ElseIf Len(theMessage) >= 31 And Len(theMessage) <= 80 Then
            howLong = 7000
        ElseIf Len(theMessage) >= 81 And Len(theMessage) <= 100 Then
            howLong = 12000
        Else
            howLong = 17000
        End If

        Me.opacityTimer.Start()
    Else
        Me.Close()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub opacityTimer_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles opacityTimer.Tick
    If isLoading Then
        Me.Opacity += 0.07

        If Me.Opacity >= 0.8 Then
            Me.opacityTimer.Stop()
            Me.opacityTimer.Dispose()
            isLoading = False
            Pause(howLong)
            Me.opacityTimer.Start()
        End If
    Else
        Me.Opacity -= 0.08

        If Me.Opacity <= 0 Then
            Form2.theNumOpened = Form2.theNumOpened - 1 'ADDED
            Me.opacityTimer.Stop()
            Me.Close()
            Me.Dispose()
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub Pause(ByVal Milliseconds As Integer)
    Dim dTimer As Date

    dTimer = Now.AddMilliseconds(Milliseconds)

    Do While dTimer > Now
        Application.DoEvents()
    Loop
End Sub
```

And how i call it is like this:

```
 Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim theForm As New frmInfo2

    Call theForm.showMessageBox("MID", "This is just a simple test here! And some more text to see how longer it is." & theNum)
    theNum = theNum + 1
 End Sub
```

David

Comment: I'd suggest posting the code where you declare the forms, where you open them and start the timers and where they are closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it by using this code:

```
Private Enum FormState
    FadeIn
    Pause
    FadeOut
End Enum

Private Sub opacityTimer_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles opacityTimer.Tick
    Select Case CurState
        Case FormState.FadeIn
            Me.Opacity += 0.07

            If Me.Opacity >= 0.8 Then
                Me.opacityTimer.Stop()
                CurState = FormState.Pause
                PreviousInterval = opacityTimer.Interval
                opacityTimer.Interval = howLong
                Me.opacityTimer.Start()
            End If

        Case FormState.Pause
            Me.opacityTimer.Stop()
            CurState = FormState.FadeOut
            opacityTimer.Interval = PreviousInterval
            Me.opacityTimer.Start()

        Case FormState.FadeOut
            Me.Opacity -= 0.08

            If Me.Opacity <= 0 Then
                Me.opacityTimer.Stop()
                Form2.theNumOpened = Form2.theNumOpened - 1 'ADDED
                Me.Close()
                Me.Dispose()
            End If
    End Select
End Sub
```

:o)

David

Answer (score 0):

Well no answers yet...

I'll chime in on some bad practices:

1. Using a DoEvents to loop
2. Using a "static" variable or property in an unknown "Form2" which seems to belong to none of the forms being used here.
3. Starting and stopping a timer inside of its own event.
4. Using Windows API calls to force form order.

I think you have more issues than just "it won't close at the right time."
Not really sure where to begin.